# Исключение числа при создании случайного списка

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на Python можно создать массив из случайных чисел, например, от -100 до 100, кроме 0?
Заполнять массив руками и использовать `random.choice`, думаю, не совсем удобно.

Comment: Если выпадет ноль, повторите получение случайного числа.

Comment: Получайте случайные числа в интервале `[-100, 99]`. Если число неотрицательное, прибавляйте единицу.

Comment: Придумайте ещё десять разных вариантов.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy благодарю!

Comment: `[randint(-100, 100) or 1 for _ in range(20)]`

Answer (score 5):

```py
from random import randint
a = [randint(-100, 100) or 1 for _ in range(20)]
```

---

Добавлю в качестве варианта основанного на предложении из коммента
*@CrazyElf*

```
a = [randint(-100, 99) or 100 for _ in range(20)]
```

Comment: Ну вот и прекрасно +, а еще писать не хотели)

Comment: Прикольно, но этот вариант даёт немного не равномерное распределение, тогда уж лучше обрезать выдачу до 99, а при нуле выдавать 100 )

Comment: @CrazyElf, кстати да. Ваше предложение выглядит дельным. Не сразу понял что Вы имеете ввиду. Добавлю Вариант, если не возражаете

Comment: Конечно не возражаю. Просто были тут уже обсуждения всяких случайных генераций и в них жёстко били канделябром за смещённое распределение ))  В данном то случае вроде и ерунда, но если легко можно сделать более хороший вариант, то лучше таки сделать

Answer (score 4):

Можете делать вот так:

```
choice((randint(-100, -1), randint(1, 99)))
```

Если у вас всегда маленькая последовательность, то можете делать вот так(Но этот способ явно не лучший вариант в общем случае, поэтому лучше использовать если границы маленькие):

```
choice([i for i in range(-100, 100) if i != 0])
```

Вообще, вариантов, как можно решить вашу проблему множество, я предлагаю лишь один из тех, которые ещё не были реализованы.

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать таким образом:

```
import random

a = 0
arr = []

def func(a):
    a = (random.randint(-100, 100))

    if a == 0:   # Если случайное число = 0, то мы повторно вызываем функцию func. Вызываться
        func(a)  # она будет до тех пор, пока число a не будет = 0

    else:
        arr.append(a)    # Если число не равно 0, то мы добавляем его в массив arr


for i in range(11):      # Цикл для заполнения массива
    
    func(a)
    
    
print(arr)
```

Comment: Лучше не использовать рекурсию в питоне. Тем более, что можно без неё прекрасно обойтись. (Минус ответу не мой, если что.)

Comment: благодарю за ответы!

Comment: Да, рекурсия и правда не лучший вариант, тем более, когда используется random

Answer (score 2):

Мне проще всего сделать так:

```
import random
n = random.randint(-100, 100)
while n == 0:
    n = random.randint(-100, 100)
```

Comment: Так можно, но нет особого смысла, если можно обойтись без дополнительных запросов к ГСЧ

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
a = [randint(-100, 100) or 1 for _ in range(20)]
```

этот вариант который привели выше не правильный. в нем количество единиц будет в два раза больше положенного. к сожалению комментарий под тем ответом оставить не могу репутации не хватает

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: А прочитать ответ полностью видимо религия не позволяет.

Comment: да прочитал. но "немного неравномерное распределение" показалось мне расплывчатым объяснением. очевидно что в такие посты заходят новички и конкретно подсказать в чем ошибка будет не лишним